# height: 100%; Won't Work

Tags: css, html, height

I can't get the following elements to extend their height to 100%.

If I don't have the text in there. They won't be visible at all.
Not exactly sure why this might be.

**Take a look [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/enbs/aW3Gk/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<figure class="left clearfix">LEFT</figure>
<figure class="middle">MID</figure>
<figure class="right clearfix">RIGHT</figure>
```

**CSS**

```
    html body figure.left {
    position: relative;

    width: -webkit-calc(50% - 20px);
    width: -moz-calc(50% - 20px);
    width: calc(50% - 20px);

    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;

    background-color: gray; 
}

    html body figure.right {
    position: relative;

    width: -webkit-calc(50% - 20px);
    width: -moz-calc(50% - 20px);
    width: calc(50% - 20px);

    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;

    background-color: orange;   
}

    html body figure.middle {
    position: relative;

    width: 40px;
    height: 100%;

    margin: 0;
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;

    background-color: black;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a "height" to your grid-container

```
html body div.grid-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px; //a height value to your grid container
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  clear: none;
  float: none;
  margin: auto;
}
```

and all you need is define 
    height: inherit;
to "html body figure.left {}" and "html body figure.right {}"

Comment: To use `inherit` your grid-container height needs to be a absolute value, like a 20px, for example.  http://jsfiddle.net/aW3Gk/24/

Comment: Right. But the height is 20px. As soon as you change the height of the grid-container to a 100%. It goes blank without the text.

Comment: And adding some paddings to left, middle and right containers? http://jsfiddle.net/aW3Gk/38/

Comment: Oh, Sorry! Now i really understand what you want... to your columns and backgrounds visually stay in 100%, you need to set html and body with a height: 100%, like @Kaushal said. http://jsfiddle.net/aW3Gk/43/

Comment: That does work, partially. Take a look at the border it makes thought: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/enbs/aW3Gk/44/)**

Comment: Set this
`html , body { height: 100%; background-color: blue; margin: 0}`
http://jsfiddle.net/aW3Gk/45/

Answer (score 0):

Please try this (http://jsfiddle.net/3MRt6/)

```
html, body, div.grid-container {
width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: auto;
clear: none;
float: none;
margin: auto;
}

figure.left {
position: relative;

width: -webkit-calc(50% - 20px);
width: -moz-calc(50% - 20px);
width: calc(50% - 20px);

height: 100%;
margin: 0;
clear: none;
float: left;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;

background-color: gray; 
}

figure.right {
position: relative;

width: -webkit-calc(50% - 20px);
width: -moz-calc(50% - 20px);
width: calc(50% - 20px);

height: 100%;
margin: 0;
clear: none;
float: left;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;

background-color: orange;   
}

 figure.middle {
position: relative;

width: 40px;
height: 100%;

margin: 0;
clear: none;
float: left;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;

background-color: black;
}
```